# Wordpress REST API remove all posts and images (media) via Python

Tags: python, python-requests, wordpress-rest-api

I feel like this should be something several other people already accomplished... to write a script that removes all sample data from a dev webpage using the Wordpress Rest API.
Right now I try to automate posting images and posts, which works and leads to several of hundreds posts and images blowing up my database.
Looking for a script doing that, neither ChatGPT nor browsing the web has provided any good answers.

Any ideas where to look for scripts like that or how to write it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope this helps someone else out in the future!!**

### Minimum Working Example (MWE)

##### 1. Configure everything to connect to Wordpress Backend

```py
import requests
import base64

def generate_auth_header():
    """Generate the authentication header for the Wordpress API."""
    try:
        user = "admin" # Set your username here
        password = "iTef fMhJ Rcij Azj3 Uban TeST" # Set your Appllication password here

        credentials = user + ":" + password

        token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())

        header = {"Authorization": "Basic " + token.decode("utf-8")}

        return header

    except IOError as e:
         raise IOError(f"Error connecting to Wordpress backend: {e}") from e

# Create header and wordpress URL
wordpress_url = 'http://localhost:10014/wp-json/wp/v2/' # Set your domain here
header = generate_auth_header()
```

**Note:** If you haven't set an Application Password yet, read [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/)

##### 2. Get all posts to delete each post by iterating

```py
# Function to get all posts
def get_all_posts():
    posts_url = f'{wordpress_url}posts?per_page=100'
    response = requests.get(posts_url, headers=header, timeout=5)
    return response.json()

# Function to delete a post by ID
def delete_post(post_id):
    delete_url = f'{wordpress_url}posts/{post_id}'
    response = requests.delete(delete_url, headers=header, timeout=5)
    return response.status_code

# Get first 100 posts
posts = get_all_posts()
print(f"posts: {posts}")

# Delete all posts iterating over 100 posts at a time
while posts != []:
    for post in posts:
        post_id = post['id']
        delete_status = delete_post(post_id)
        if delete_status in [200, 201]:
            print(f"Post {post_id} deleted successfully.")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to delete post {post_id}, status code: {delete_status}")

    posts = get_all_posts()
```

**Note:** The query string `?per_page=100` in the GET-posts URL makes things easier instead of iterating over the default 10 posts at a time.

##### 3. Get all images to delete each image by iterating

```py
# Function to get all images
def get_all_media():
    media_url = f'{wordpress_url}media?per_page=100'
    response = requests.get(media_url, headers=header, timeout=5)
    return response.json()

# Function to delete each image by ID
def delete_media(media_id):
    delete_url = f'{wordpress_url}media/{media_id}?force=1'
    response = requests.delete(delete_url, headers=header, timeout=5)
    return response.status_code

# Get and delete all media (images)
media = get_all_media()
print(f"media: {media}")

# Delete all media (images) iterating over 100 images at a time
while media != []:
    for media_item in media:
        media_id = media_item['id']
        delete_status = delete_media(media_id)
        if delete_status in [200, 201]:
            print(f"Media {media_id} deleted successfully.")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to delete media {media_id}, status code: {delete_status}")

    media = get_all_media()
```

**Note:** Without the query string `?force=1` deleting images did not work for me.